# Reversing inner sequence of list items using a function and for loop.

Tags: python, list, reverse

I need help understanding a homework assignment that has been giving me a TON of trouble. I have attempted many different methods to get the following assignment to produce the desired result:

> 1. Create a module named task_05.py
> 2. Create a function named flip_keys() that takes one argument:
>       a. A list named to_flip. This list is assumed to have nested, immutable            sequences inside it, eg: [(1, 2, 3), 'hello']
> 3. Use a for loop to loop the list and reverse the order of the inner sequence. All operations on the outer list must operate on the
>      original object, taking advantage of its mutability. Inner elements
>      are immutable and will require replacement.
> 4. The function should return the original list with its inner elements reversed.

My professor will evaluate the result of my script by imputing the following into python shell:

```
>>> LIST = [(1, 2, 3), 'abc']
>>> NEW = flip_keys(LIST)
>>> LIST is NEW
True
>>> print LIST
[(3, 2, 1), 'cba']
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and my professor hasn't responded. Students also havent responded and I have reviewed the material multiple times to try to find the answer. Something isn't clicking in my brain.

He provided the following hints, which I believe I have implimented in my script:

> Hint
>
> Consider how to access or change the value of a list. You did it
>   already in task 2!
>
> Hint
>
> In order to change the value in to_flip you'll need some way to know
>   which index you're attempting to change. To do-this, create a variable
>   to act as a counter and increment it within your loop, eg:
>
> counter = 0 for value in iterable_object:
>
> ## do something counter += 1 Now consider what that counter could represent. At the end of this loop does counter ==
>
> len(iterable_object)
>
> Hint
>
> For an idea on how to reverse a tuple, head back to an earlier
>   assignment when you reversed a string using the slice syntax.

Heres my latest script without comments (because I don't write them in until the script works):

```
def flip_keys(to_flip):
    for loop_list in to_flip:
        to_flip = [to_flip[0][::-1], to_flip[1][::-1]]
        return to_flip
```

When I test the script using the commands pasted above, I get these results:

```
>>>LIST = [(1, 2, 3), 'abc']
>>>NEW = flip_keys(LIST)
>>>LIST is NEW 
False
>>>print flip_keys(LIST) 
[(3, 2, 1), 'cba']
>>>print LIST 
[(1, 2, 3), 'abc']
```

The goal of the assignment is to experiement with mutability, which I think I understand. The problem I'm facing is that the LIST variable is suppose to be updated by the function, but this never happens.

The following is supposed to evaluate to True, not false. And then print the reversed list value stored in the LIST constant.

```
>>>LIST = [(1, 2, 3), 'abc']
>>>NEW = flip_keys(LIST)
>>>LIST is NEW False
```

please let me know if this is enough information. I have spent way too much time on this and at this point my assignment is 4 days late and I'm receiving no support from professor or students (I've informed my adviser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a new list from your function. Use a full slice `[:]` assignment to do an *in-place* mutation of the original list.

You can also use the more conventional way for creating lists - *list comprehension* - instead of the for loop:

```
def flip_keys(to_flip):
    to_flip[:] = [i[::-1] for i in to_flip]
    return to_flip
```

---

**Test**

```
>>> LIST = [(1, 2, 3), 'abc']
>>> NEW = flip_keys(LIST)
>>> NEW
[(3, 2, 1), 'cba']
>>> NEW is LIST
True
```

<sub>IMO, mutating a mutable argument and returning it doesn't feel right/conventional. This could make for a good discussion in your next class.</sub>

Comment: I think if i update my answer it will look like yours. So i'll delete mine. +1 :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think this task is simply to demonstrate mutability of immutable data types in a list. I don't recall seeing syntax like this in class, but I think I understand whats happening. 

to_flip[:] is telling python to look at each value in the list. The loop that mutates the values is declaring a local variable to store each value from  to_flip, then reversing it and adding it back into the list. Am I right? Is there a better way to explain this?

Comment: Sort of, but the variable is local to the comprehension (in Python 3). Flip each of the items to create a new object and then build a new list with those. Update the old list with values from the new using the full slice assignment

Comment: Is this syntax introduced in python 3.0 only? I'm using 2.7.6 (i believe). Definitely not version 3.

Comment: Also, how would you address this task to do it in a conventional way? I'm very curious to know, if you wouldnt mind.

Comment: It works in 2.7 also. You could build a new list using a for loop and then update the original using the full slice assignment I have shown

Comment: Great, thanks so much for all of your help. I understand this now and am looking forward to practicing.